# Cardinality of the set of primes that are not Fibonacci primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the set of prime numbers that are not Fibonacci numbers, $ \mathbb{P}_{\neq \mathcal{F}} = \mathbb{P} \setminus \mathcal{F} $.

The first few numbers in this set are $\mathbb{P}_{\neq \mathcal{F}} = \{7, 11, 17, 19, 23, 29, ...\}$

Can it be shown that $|\mathbb{P}_{\neq \mathcal{F}}| = \aleph_{0}$?

In other words, can it be shown that there are an infinite number of prime numbers that are not Fibonacci numbers?

A comment: note that if the cardinality of $\mathbb{P}_{\neq \mathcal{F}}$ was finite, then the number of Fibonacci primes would necessarily be infinite (which is an open question). However, $|\mathbb{P}_{\neq \mathcal{F}}| = \aleph_{0}$ does not indicate anything about the number of Fibonacci primes.

Comment: Bertrand's postulate famously states that there is at least one prime in between numbers $n$ and $2n$ for each $n$. What would be sufficient to answer your question positively is a stronger version of BP that states that there is always a prime between $n$ and $1.6n$. I believe this is true (just less famous) but I am no expert on this topic. Perhaps googling for 'strengthening of Bertrand's Postulate' can help you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results

Comment: @Chappers Would it be correct to state that the Nagura result (there is always a prime between $n$ and $1.2n$ for $ n \ge 25$) is sufficient to demonstrate that the number of primes between each Fibonacci number increases without bound as $ n \rightarrow \infty $?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Proof:  The sum of the reciprocals of the Fibonacci numbers converges (by comparison with a geometric series or by the ratio test).  However the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) for instance.